# How can I express that the number of classes and screens in the application must be equal?

Tags: phrase-request

An Android application consists of one or more than one screen. The android developers define a special structure for each screen in an application. These structures are called "class".

How can I express it in one sentence? ( My intention is to specify the number of classes and screens in the application must be equal )

> The developers should define as many classes as the number of screens in the application.
>
> The developers should define a class for every window in the application.

Are they correct?

If they are not, how can I express this?

Comment: Anyway, because you are asking about the specific language of Android development, and not general English language, I think this question is better suited to one of the programming forums. It's important to use the precise language of a software development platform, otherwise readers might get confused

Comment: @Andrew If we substitute "circles" and "triangles" for "classes" and "screens" this question has nothing to do with programming. The way I read it, it is about expressing that the two structures must be equal in number or have a 1:1 relationship regardless of the proper term is for those structures. If the question was about whether to use "class" and "screen" then this would probably be better suited on a different SE site.

Comment: @ColleenV  Possibly, although I still think it's the subject matter that creates this kind of comparison -- and the answer is best addressed with the appropriate jargon.   If we were talking about circles or triangles, for example, you wouldn't use the verb *define*.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the programming argument aside, both of your sentences are correct. I will add another alternative:

> Each screen should be its own class.

Answer (score 0):

In the application, there are probably other *classes* used than just for the displays.  *Classes* are something particular to programming.

What you might want to say is

> Each window/display should **be a class**.

That way you will have at least one class for each display.

Answer (score 0):

OP writes:

> My intention is to specify the number of classes and screens in the
>   application must be equal

Setting aside the issue of whether this is correct or incorrect from a programming perspective, and using your terminology...

You could say:

> Each screen in an Android app is uniquely associated with a class.

or

> Every screen in an Android app is defined by its own class.

or

> Each screen in an Android app has its own class.